# Trying to run a .AppImage on a remote server, keep getting Missing X server or $DISPLAY

Tags: linux, ubuntu, application, appimage

I'm trying to install [Nvidia's Omniverse](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/omniverse/download/) on my remote server. However, whenever I install the `.AppImage` and then run it after chmodding it (as per the instrctions) I keep running into the following error:

```
./omniverse-launcher-linux.AppImage 
[2482073:0110/151536.190895:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[2482073:0110/151536.190942:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't have a display attached to this remote server, which I guess explains the error. Is there a way around this? How to solve?

Would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: If you are using `ssh` to access it you could try X11 Forwarding.